# Approximate a definite integral to three decimal places: $\int_0^2 \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{64+x^3}}$.

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals, approximation

I try to expand function $$\frac1{\sqrt[3]{64+x^3}}$$ using Maclaurin series. So, $f(x) = 64{(1+ \frac{x^3}{64})}^{-1/3}$. I expand it and I get $$64\sum_0^n(-1)^n\frac{\left(\frac13\right)\ldots\left(\frac23-n\right)}{(3n+1)}{\left(\frac1{64}\right)}^nx^{3n}$$.

So, even assuming that I expanded $f(x)$ correctly, I am unable to evaluate the answer.
The result I am getting seems to be way too big, assuming that I have not been mislead by online definite integral calculators...

With that said, I think the answer should be around $0.495$, however I failed to dig up to it.

Any ideas how do I do it?

Comment: $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{64+x^3}}=\int\frac{dx}{4\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{x^3}{64}}}=\int(1-\frac{x^3}{192})\frac{dx}4=\frac14(x-\frac{x^4}{768})=0.495$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{2}{\dd x \over \root[3]{64 + x^{3}}}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\int_{0}^{2}{\dd x \over \root[3]{64 + x^{3}}}=
> \int_{0}^{1/2}{\dd x \over \root[3]{x^{3} + 1}}
> =\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}\int_{0}^{1/2}x^{3n}\,\dd x
> =\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}\,{1 \over 2^{3n + 1}\pars{3n + 1}}
> \end{align}
>   Find the first $n$ such that $\ds{a_{n}}$ satisfies
>   $\ds{\verts{a_{n}\,{1 \over 2^{3n + 1}\pars{3n + 1}}} < 10^{-4}\quad\imp\quad
> \verts{a_{n}} < 2^{3n + 1}\pars{3n + 1}\,10^{-4}}$

It turns out that $\ds{n \leq 3}$:
$$
\int_{0}^{2}{\dd x \over \root[3]{64 + x^{3}}}
\approx \sum_{n = 0}^{3}{a_{n} \over 2^{3n + 1}\pars{3n + 1}}\,,
\qquad
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{rcr}
a_{0} & = & 1
\\
a_{1} & = & -\,{1 \over 3}
\\
a_{2} & = & {2 \over 9}
\\
a_{3} & = & -\,{14 \over 81}
\end{array}\right.
$$

> $$
> \int_{0}^{2}{\dd x \over \root[3]{64 + x^{3}}}
> \approx \half - {1 \over 192} + {1 \over 4032} - {7 \over 414720}
> ={1437071 \over 2903040} \approx \color{#c00000}{\large 0.495}0228037
> $$

Result: $\ds{\color{#00f}{\large\approx 0.495}}$

Comment: Please explain how $$\frac1{\sqrt[3]{64+x^3}} = \frac1{\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}}$$, what $a_n$ is equal to and how do you get $$\int_0^{\frac12} x^{3n}dx$$ from $$\int_0^{\frac12}\frac1{\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}}$$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just perform the integral using some quadrature rule, say a three point quadrature (a.k.a Simpson's rule):
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx \approx \frac{b-a}{6}\left[f(a) + 4f\left(\tfrac{a+b}{2}\right)+f(b)\right]$$
Then subdivide until you reach the desired accuracy.
In this case, the basic rule is enough with no subdivisions.